# In matlab why is the 1st digit in a binary notation being discarded?

Tags: matlab

When i try to display binary notations which start with a zero in the 1st bit position, matlab discards the zero and displays only the other 7 bits. How do I display the 1st position too? 
ex: when i try to display "01101111", matlab displays it as "1101111", but I need the 1st bit position value also. Can some one please help.

Comment: Can you be more explicit on how you are trying to display the number? Some code would help

Comment: @Dan I have just given Z = [01001111] , so it should display 01001111, but it displays 1001111.

Comment: @charvi: `Z = [01001111]` doesn't create an array (well it does, but it's a 1x1 scalar number)... Put spaces or commas in between: `Z = [0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1]`

Comment: @charvi to add to what Amro has correctly answered, if you typed `Z = 0034` you'd expect it to return `34` so if `z = 0100` then it should also just return `100` because by default numbers are decimal not binary in Matlab. The way to represent a binary number is either as an array (i.e. [0,1,0,0]) or as a string (i.e. `'0100'`) but you probably want the former

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Matlab, **to display** the bit representation of a number you need to convert it into a string with [`dec2bin()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/dec2bin.html).

So, if you have `x = 111`, it's binary representation is:

```
dec2bin(111)
ans =
1101111
```

which retains only the **significant** bits. To force an 8-bit representation use:

```
dec2bin(111,8)
ans =
01101111
```

Note, how the result will be a **string**. If you want to retrieve bits in numeric format, then use [`bitget()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/bitget.html):

```
bitget(111,8:-1:1)
ans =
  0     1     1     0     1     1     1     1
```

Basically, if your need is purely visual, use `dec2bin2()` otherwise for manipulating bits, use the [bit-wise operations functions](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/bit-wise-operations.html), which accept and return numeric types.